# Does IBM LTO4 HH can power up on RAID B120i or is it dead drive?

Tags: lto-4

I've purchased IBM LTO4 HH in enclosure (SAS) as I do not have external SAS cable I wanted to use it from 5.25" bay, however when I tried to boot up from my MicroServer G8 (only spare server which I was able to shutdown to play with) (RAID card is B120i), drive is not powering up nor starting.

Nothing like a dead drive (no lights, nothing, tape can't be inserted).

I was thinking if this is because of this drives requires ~4-5A 5-12V, while most of drives is taking up to 1A so I was thinking that SAS line on it's own isn't able to provide enough of amperage to start this drive up...

Is it true ????

I will add that this drive in enclosure without connected SAS cable shows same symptoms, no lights, nothing (only enclosure shows power light).

So now I am not sure if drive won't work on normal SAS cable connected in hard drive bay (I just unscrew the cable for HDD and just connected it to the drive) AND won't work without connected SAS cable to the enclosure (what would make sense) or is this is just dead drive and I should return as DOA...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds a little crazy, and you may be confused.

SAS doesn't provide power.

You will need to find an external power source for your tape drive.

Comment: Oh, So I guess I have to use it in enclosure... So is it normal that drive while installed in enclosure is not starting up without SAS cable connected ? I just want to know if drive is damaged or if this is common behaviour. I am waiting on SAS cable but it might take few days and I might have less days to return it.